# Logic of computing a^b, and is power a keyword?

Tags: recursion, syntax, logic, keyword, pseudocode

I found the following code that is meant to compute a^b (Cracking the Coding Interview, Ch. VI Big O).

- What's the logic of `return a * power(a, b - 1);` ? Is it recursion
  of some sort?
- Is power a keyword here or just pseudocode?

  ```
  int power(int a, int b) 
         { if (b < 0) {
            return a; // error 
         } else if (b == 0) {
             return 1; 
         } else {
             return a * power(a, b - 1); 
         }    
     }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Power is just the name of the function.

Ya this is RECURSION as we are representing a given problem in terms of smaller problem of similar type.

let **a=2** and **b=4** =calculate= **power(2,4)**   -- large problem (original one)
Now we will represent this in terms of smaller one
i.e  **2*power(2,4-1)** -- smaller problem of same type **power(2,3)**

 i.e **a*power(a,b-1)**

If's in the start are for controlling the base cases i.e when **b** goes below 1

Answer (score 0):

`power` here is just the name of the function that is defined and NOT a keyword.

Now, let consider that you want to find `2^10`. You can write the same thing as `2*(2^9)`, `as 2*2*(2^8)`, as `2*2*2*(2^7)` and so on till `2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*(2^1)`.

This is what `a * power(a, b - 1)` is doing in a recursive manner.

Here is a dry run of the code for finding `2^4`:
The initial call to the function will be `power(2,4)`, the complete stack trace is shown below

```
power(2,4) ---> returns a*power(2,3), i.e, 2*4=16
    |
power(2,3) ---> returns a*power(2,2), i.e, 2*3=8
    |
power(2,2) ---> returns a*power(2,1), i.e, 2*2=4
    |
power(2,1) ---> returns a*power(2,0), i.e, 2*1=2
    |
power(2,0) ---> returns 1 as b == 0
```

Comment: On a side note: Try performing a dry-run of the algorithm,  that is tracing its output by going through all its step, it might help you understand the algorithm better.

Comment: Thanks! Would you know how the portion `power(a, b - 1)` achieves the computation of the power? I don't see any operators inside the parentheses, so I'm not sure how it's done. Also, how does it go through all the values of b, if there is no for loop?

Comment: @legalalien I have edited my answer to include the dry run, please see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function. That is, the function is defined in terms of itself, with a base case that prevents the recursion from running indefinitely.

`power` is the name of the function.

For example, `4^3` is equal to `4 * 4^2`. That is, `4` raised to the third power can be calculated by multiplying `4` and *`4` raised to the second power*. And `4^2` can be calculated as `4 * 4^1`, which can be simplified to `4 * 4`, since the base case of the recursion specifies that `4^1 = 4`. Combining this together, `4^3 = 4 * 4^2 = 4 * 4 * 4^1 = 4 * 4 * 4 = 64`.

Comment: I added an edit to your answer, thinking it was mine. Please ignore it, sorry for the trouble.